# PHP Script Weird Behaviour

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite baffled by this. I have the following code in a php script, everything works fine except the description field. As you can see in the output in the Advanced REST client the description field is not set. I do not understand why something like this would be happening :

```
if (isset($_POST['latitude']) && $_POST['longitude'] && $_POST['image'] && $_POST['user'] && $_POST['description'] != '') {
// get tag
$latitude= $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude= $_POST['longitude'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$description= $POST['description'];
$min = 10000.0;
$uuid = random_str(32,'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
echo $latitude;
echo "BREAK";
echo $longitude;
echo "BREAK";
echo $image;
echo "BREAK";
echo $user; 
echo "BREAK";
echo $description; 
echo "BREAK";
```

[image]

Comment: There's probably a warning somewhere in your logs telling you that `$POST` doesn't exist or that indexing it as an array is undefined.

Comment: `$POST` is wrong and also `if` condition badly need some change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two really important things:-**

1.`$description= $POST['description'];` needs to be `$description= $_POST['description'];` `_` missed by you

2.`if` condition need to be changed like below:-

```
if (isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['longitude']) && isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {
```

Note:- `&& $_POST['longitude']` and so on others in your `if` will not do anything so useless. Since `isset()` check that a variable is set and have some value or not so use it for all `$_POST` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax error, Replace `$POST` with `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling variable `$POST` instead of `$_POST`.

You should write:

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
```